# Count the number of strings of length 8 over A = {w, x, y, z} that begins with either w or y and have at least one x

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Count the number of strings of length $8$ over $A = \{w, x, y, z\}$ that begins with either $w$ or $y$ and have at least one $x$

So here is what I came up with..Can someone check my work?

$A = \{w,x,y,z\}$

$U = \{w,y\} * A^7$

$S = \{w,y\} * \{w,y,z\}^7$

$|U - S| = |U| - |S|$

$= |\{w,y\} * A^7| - |\{w,y\} * \{w,y,z\}^7|$

$= |\{w,y\}||A|^7 - |\{w,y\}||\{w,y,z\}|^7$

$= 2(4^7) - 2(3^7) = 28,394$

Comment: Makes sense to me

Comment: The numerical answer is correct. Perhaps too many symbols, too few words.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are $2$ ways to select from $\{w, y\}$ for the first place, and of the $4^7$ ways to select from all the letters into the remaining seven places, $3^7$ do not include any $x$.   So the ways to fill the required pattern are:$$\lvert \{w, y\} \times (\{w,x,y,z\}^7\setminus\{w, y, z\}^7)\rvert = 2\cdot (4^7-3^7)$$
In an exam it's advisable to include *some* words, to indicate you grok what the symbols represent.   However, you seem to have grasped the concept and just need to work on presentation.

Comment: This is straight from the book by the way lol...so yeah. They just changed the numbers.. as far as "presentation" goes..